# can I have both JDO and JPA annotations at the same time?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

What will actually happen if I provide a full set of annotations for JPA and JDO on data objects?

Can I then switch between them without touching the code? how can I switch what to aplay external configuration files? I know in the META-INF there are persistence.xml jdoconfig.xml but I do not understand the how to use them. (may be a link to a compressive explanation?) 
Currently I got both files in place and the code below compiles Ok. I am interested in what goes under the hood to understand implications of this approach.

For vivid example:

```
@Entity
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
class B
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long   id;

    @Persistent
    @Basic
    private String name;
}
```

Platform: default setup of Google AppEngine 1.4 it uses DataNucleus Enhancer (version 1.1.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I have never try this it should work. This is the point of annotations: the do not affect the code unless they are used. JPA implementation uses its annotations, JDO uses others.

Comment: that is clear to me... BUT in this case there generally same enhancer is running and adding bytecode to the class and than there a code executed. What will happen in runtime?

Comment: when you invoke the enhancer you specify the API being used